# Is it possible to add a "smaller" border around a button that is a in stack view?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uistackview

So I have a single button that is kept in a vertical stack view.  Before the stack view, my border was directly connected to my button.  however, now that my button is in a stack view, the border now attaches itself to the confines of the stack view - as pictured.  Is it possible to re-attach the border just to the button text and not the view?[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Attributes Inspector, change the Alignment from Fill to Center:

[image: Alignment]

Comment: unfortunately the change did not alter the border position.